# Using the ASCII value of a parameter in Where clause of LinqDataSource

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql

I have a LinqDataSource. This data source reads from a table in SQL Server that contains a field called ID, which is of type CHAR. Some of the records have blanks in this field and I would like to filter these out. The "blank" is not NULL and not an empty string.

Using T-SQL, this clause fails to filter the records properly:

```
WHERE Employee_ID <> ''
```

...while this one succeeds:

```
WHERE ASCII(Employee_ID) <> 0
```

Now my question is, how do I configure the LinqDataSource in design mode to filter by the ASCII value of the field or how can I otherwise filter so these records are not returned?

This is the markup of the data source:

```
 <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSourcePersonnel" runat="server" ContextTypeName="exc009p.Owner_SummariesDataContext"
    EntityTypeName="" TableName="Personnels" Select='new(Employee_ID, Employee_Name, Employee_Title, (Employee_ID + " " + Employee_Name + " - " + Employee_Title) as employeeIDNameTitle)'
    OrderBy="Employee_Name, Employee_ID" Where="Employee_ID != @Employee_ID">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="&quot;&quot;" Name="Employee_ID" Type="String" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Comment: I'll venture to guess something close to `Where="Employee_ID != @Employee_ID && Employee_ID != '\0'"` or `Where="Employee_ID != @Employee_ID && System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.Ascii(Employee_ID) == 0`

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - thanks for the response, however, in using your first suggestion I get "_Character literal must contain exactly one character_", and your second suggestion yielded "_No property of field 'System' exists in type 'Personnel'_". Any other ides?

Comment: Hm, maybe you need to skip the namespace, `Where="Employee_ID != @Employee_ID && SqlFunctions.Ascii(Employee_ID) != 0"`.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - unfortunately that did not work either. I got _No property or field 'SqlFunctions' exists in type 'Personnel'_

Comment: Ok, one last attempt ;) `Where="Employee_ID != @Employee_ID && Int32(Employee_ID[0]) != 0"` works in Linq to Objects at least. Found the reason SqlFunctions worked for me before, I added it to `predefinedTypes` in the dynamic linq source, guess that's not an option in this case.

Comment: Tack sa mycket! That worked. If you wish, you can post as an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the root of your issue is that you have non-printable characters in your column (tab, CR, LF etc...)  When you query runs the result looks like a blank but it in fact has a non printable character.

I think the best coarse of action would be to validate data (in the application) to make sure only valid characters are inserted into this column.  This will prevent you from having to use a make shift filter.

If you cannot change the data or validate the data, I would probably try something like this,as it is SARGable (can be used for an index seek)

```
select *
from MyTable
WHERE employee like '[a-z0-9]%'
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't have control of how the application writes to the database I am reading from. I'm not sure how to get the LIKE clause you mention into the markup but I'll give it a try. Thanks.